# Capture view() output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to create a RMarkdown file in html using the knit. Here is an example of one of my code chunk:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
results=sqldf('SELECT airline, COUNT(airline) num_tweets, 
              100.0*SUM(CASE WHEN airline_sentiment="negative" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(airline) percent_negative, 
              100.0*SUM(CASE WHEN airline_sentiment="neutral"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(airline) percent_neutral, 
              100.0*SUM(CASE WHEN airline_sentiment="positive" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(airline) percent_positive 
              FROM Tweets 
              GROUP BY airline 
              ORDER BY 100.0*SUM(CASE WHEN airline_sentiment="negative" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(airline) DESC')
View(results)
```
````

But now when I run the knit to compile everything to a html file, the `view()` output is not getting captured in the resulting html file. I am not using just the `results` because I want my output to be in tabular order.

Kindly provide your suggestions on how can this be done.

Comment: you might be interested in the recent rstudio update that supports html notebooks. You would then just print results to the console.

Comment: Is using kable and jQuery Datatables an appropriate replacement: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/datatables.html

Comment: @mnel: Thank you very much. That did the trick

Comment: Note that `CASE WHEN airline_sentiment="negative" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` can be written as just `airline_sentiment="negative"` .